# path smooth algorithm for astar path planning based on quad tree

Tags: a-star, quadtree

I implement an astar path finding method based on quad tree(the grids are difference in size, it's the main case), now I can get the rough path, but I don't get a smooth method to optimize the path, anyone who has one or reference may helps, thanks.

Comment: the path finding algorithm is reference from [the web](http://mathieuturcotte.ca/textes/quadtree/)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

haha,I find the method for the difference size path smooth. Just use the funnel algorithm too, but there is a difference: when add left and right point for two quads, find one intersection side, and sort the four points(a0, a1, b0, b1) like ([x, y0], [x, y1], [x, y2], [x, y3], and y0 <= y1 <= y2 <= y3) , and use the two points [x, y1], [x, y2].

Comment: anybody need the algorithm can seed email to fieldchao@gmail.com